# Continue in while with mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop, continue

I have a few lines of code, but can't find the right way to use it properly.

```
$cc = 0;
$tt = 50;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

//building array with values from DB.

    if (++$cc < $tt)
        continue;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $tt; $i++) {

    //Work with the array

    }
}
```

Let's say I have 133 results in DB. It'll get first 50 - do something in the for loop, then 50 more, will go thru the for loop again and will stop.
The last 33 results will be untouched.
It'll get them, but cause can't reach 50 will stop and they won't go through the for loop.

My problems is how to "send" them in the loop down there?

Comment: what are these loops? I have a strong feeling that they are quite similar and you actually need only one.

Comment: No.
While loop is to get records from DB and build array.
With the for loop I run 'threads'(multithreading[curl_multi_getcontent and etc.]).

So I need both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the for loop in a function and call it after the while loop:

```
$cc = 0;
$tt = 50;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

//building array with values from DB.

    if (++$cc < $tt) continue;

    work_with_array($array);
}
if($cc) work_with_array($array);

function work_with_array($array) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        //Work with the array
    }
}
```

Comment: @M42, I think you meant to do $i<count($array) inside the function, right? $i<$tt isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$i = 0
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):
  if($i < 50):
   //Code when $i is less than 50
   //Insert code here

  elseif($i > 50 && $i < 100):
   //Code when $i is more than 50 but less than 100
   //Insert code here

  elseif($i > 100):
   //Code when $i is more than 100
   //Insert code here

  endif;
 $i++;
endwhile;
```

So all results are going through this loop. If $i is less than 50 (or if the result is less than 50) then some code is executed, or if $i is more than 50 but less than 100 then some different code is executed. Finally if $i is more than 100 then some other code is executed.

Do you understand?

Comment: You don't consider cases `$i == 50` and `$i == 100`

Comment: I don't have to > means more than x. And < means less than or equal to.

Comment: Really? Where did you see that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$i = 0
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) && $i < 100):
  if($i < 50):
   //Code when $i is less than 50
  else:
   //Code more than or equal to 50
  endif;
 $i++;

endwhile;
```

Comment: Can't get the logic here. Can u explain?
And I'm trying to keep the structure of the code.

Comment: Here you are basically telling the script if $i is less than 100 then load the loop. So the first 100 results will be shown. Then the if statement is saying if $i is less than then run this code, or else (if $i is more than 50), run this code. At the end I added $i++; so at the end of each loop $i goes up in value. When $i reaches 100 the loop will stop.

Comment: So the code will stop when it get 100 results from DB, right? I don't want this.
I want to get ALL records from DB, build an array and work with this array in the for loop.

Sorry if I've got it wrong, but it pretty confusing.

Comment: Do you want all 133 results in the array?

Comment: So... look at my code.
I work with them on "pieces". First I get 50, doing something with them, then get 50 more, doing something and I want to get last 33 and also do something with them, but I can't get them, cause $cc can't reach 50 but just 33.

Comment: I will post another answer then, hold on.

Answer (score 0):

All the continues inside the loop seem unneccesary. If you're simply trying to process the entire result set and do something in chunks, you can do this

```
$cc = 0;
$tt = 50;
$result_array = array();

// this will chunk your array into blocks
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    //building array with values from DB.
    $result_array[intval($cc++/$tt)] = $row;

}

// at this point you should have result_array with indexes:0,1,2 and have subarrays with 50, 50, 33 entries each.


foreach ($result_array as $k=>$sub_array) {
    //Work with your sub array
    foreach ($sub_array as $one_row)
    {
       // do something with the row
    }
}
```

I do agree with @Col.Shrapnel though. Why are you creating another array inside the while loop just to go through that array one row at a time to do something? It would've made sense if you send out a batch of data at once (like bulk insert into db, sure) but to loop through again seems odd. Why can't you do the same right in the while loop

Comment: Yup. I'm using batches and DB insert/update in this for loop.

Comment: @user1043744,ok. If you're doing batch inserts, you can still process your rows inside the while loop (without the need for extra for loop). When counter reaches 50 (test with $cc % 50 == 0) do your bulk insert. After the while loop is done, do another bulk insert to get the rest.

Comment: I've got the idea.
But I need to limit the batches.
I've used the M42's solution to get this thing works.

Thanks for your time too. I appreciate it! :)